# how can i dynamically calculate and draw canvas border from user input

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, canvas

I am new to the canvas. My requirement is to  draw rectangle in SVG  And I have achieved this with the d3 library.

```
             this.borderWidth = 300 //(dynamic value);
               this.maxWidth = 600;
             this.borderHeight = 400; //(dynamic value);
            this.maxHeight = 600;
             var svg = d3.select(this.child.canvas.current).append('svg')
                .attr('id','Preview')
                .attr('width', this.borderWidth)
                .attr('height', this.borderHeight)
                .style('border', '1px solid black')
```

But I have to draw border dynamically from the input field which should not cross
**this.maxWidth** value and    **this.maxHeight** value

but then input filed value is coming in cm( centimeter unit);

The problem is when the user puts a large input value then the border will cross max width and max-height

How can I draw a border from the input field which should be in between max-width and max-height dynamically?
Please help me to find a solution by calculating the relative dimension

Answer (score 1):

If the user input is a value in centimer, you'd have to find out which one is the biggest, for example, if he enters 20cm of width and 5cm of height :

```
width = maxwidth
height = 5/20 * maxheight
```

Then your rectangle should be the right ratio and will never go beyond the maxwidth or maxheight (note that some specific rectangle like squares might be a problem).

Comment: ` let maxWidth = 600,
         let  maxHeight = 600;
         let borderWidth = 3;
         let borderHeight = 11;
      let borderAspectRatio = borderWidth / borderHeight;
      if (borderAspectRatio > 1) {
         maxHeight = maxWidth / borderAspectRatio;
      } else {
        maxWidth = maxHeight * borderAspectRatio;
      }
`
i have implemented like this

is this correct?
'

Comment: I would've done something like that, but then i'm not sure, try it to figure out what works best :
` let maxWidth = 600, let maxHeight = 600; let borderWidth = 3; let borderHeight = 11; let borderAspectRatio = borderWidth / borderHeight; if (borderAspectRatio > 1) { borderWidth = maxWidth; borderHeight = borderAspectRatio*maxHeight } else { borderHeight = maxHeight; borderWidth = maxWidth / borderAspectRatio; } `
Then you can draw your rectangle based on borderWidth and borderHeight.